# Intermittent SaveFailedException on FactoryMuffin Confide user creation

Tags: php, laravel-4, factorymuffin

For a Laravel project using the Confide package I've tried to create a Factory Muffin (v2.1) definition for creating Users in integration tests.

```
FactoryMuffin::define('User', [
'username'      => 'randomNumber|6',
'email'         => 'unique:email',
'password'      => function() { return 'test123'; },
'password_confirmation' => function() { return 'test123'; },
'confirmed'     => function() { return 1; },
'confirmation_code' => function() { return md5(microtime().Config::get('app.key')); }
```

]);

However, during testing I get the following error, but only some of the time.

> League\FactoryMuffin\Exceptions\SaveFailedException: We could not save the model of type: 'User'.

I've looked up the source of this exception and tried printing the model creation errors, but these appear empty.

I've also looked at Confide's UserValidator, but as far as I can see, the generated user should validate.

Has anyone encountered this problem before, or see something I have overlooked?

Comment: I noticed you tagged this as Laravel 4, have you tried in Laravel 5?

Comment: I haven't upgraded the project from 4.2 to 5 yet. But I will try a case to see if it solves this.

Comment: I would definitely say try that, package could be having compatibility issues. It's a fairly straight forward process to upgrade, but you could still have a lot of issues.

Comment: It appears Confide is unfortunately not updated to laravel5  (yet). So it seems unlikely compatiblity issues are the source of the problem. Thanks for your suggestion though @Zarathuztra. It could still be something that has been resolved in laravel 5 but not in 4